# python kivy screen confog

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

```
main.py file  
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
class Hero(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("stackoverflow.kv")
Hero().run()
```

the above is the main.py file
please guys help me with this

stackoverflow.kv file

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screenmanager
    Screen:
        id: accountscreen
        name: "screen1"
        BoxLayout:
            oreintation: "vertical"
            MDGridLayout:
                cols:1## Heading ##
               MDLabel:
                    text: "[color=00FF00]Sign In[/color]"
                    bold:True
                    markup:True
                    halign: "center"
                    valign: "middle"
                MDTextField:
                    id: username
                    padding: "30dp"
                    spacing: "30dp"
                    hint_text:"User Name or Email"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
                MDTextField:
                    id:password
                    padding: "20dp"
                    spacing: "20dp"
                    hint_text:"Password"
                MDRectangleFlatButton:
                    text:"Sign In"
                    padding: "16dp"
                    spacing: "16dp"
                    halign: "center"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x":.9,"center_y":.5}
                    on_press: app.root.current="screen2"

                BoxLayout:
                    oreintation: "vertical"
    Screen:
        id: welcome_screen
        name: "screen2"
        MDLabel:
            text: "welcome"
            valign: "middle"
            halign: "center"
```

any time i open the app i get the sign in screen how can i save the user information and clear the screen using config ini file please help me????

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of you code that uses `Config` to do what you want:

```
import os
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Hero(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = Builder.load_file("stackoverflow.kv")
        self.load_my_config()
        sm.current = self.initial_screen
        return sm

    def build_config(self, config):
        # Make sure that the config has at least default entries that we need
        config.setdefaults('app', {
            'startup_screen': 'screen1',
        })

    def get_application_config(self):
        # This defines the path and name where the ini file is located
        return str(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Hero.ini'))

    def on_stop(self):
        # save the config when the app exits
        self.save_config()

    def save_config(self):
        # this writes the data we want to save to the config

        # set the data in the config
        self.config.set('app', 'startup_screen', 'screen2')

        # write the config file
        self.config.write()

    def load_my_config(self):
        # extract our saved data from the config (it has already been read)
        self.initial_screen = self.config.get('app', 'startup_screen', fallback='screen1')

Hero().run()
```

And in the `kv` file, I would add a call to save the configuration when the `Sign In` button is pressed:

```
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text:"Sign In"
                padding: "16dp"
                spacing: "16dp"
                halign: "center"
                pos_hint: {"center_x":.9,"center_y":.5}
                on_press:
                    app.root.current="screen2"
                    app.save_config()
```